# JavaFX - Iterate GridPane nodes per row - Read Nodes of GridPane per row

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I am creating an application using JavaFX 8.
I change the content of a grid pane dynamically using drag/drop.
I wish to iterate GridPane contents per row or per row/col. 
JavaFX allows adding nodes in a GridPane by specifying the row and column.

```
gridPane.add(node, col, row);
```

I would like to read the nodes of a GridPane on the same way, by specifying the row and column.
I would like to have something similar to the below source (the below code is not correct),

```
for(int row = 0; row < gridPaneHeight; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; row < gridPaneWidth; col++) {
        Node node = gridPane.get(col, row);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no code above .do you mean the code below

Comment: Wrong word. I am sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
int[][] gridPaneNodes = new int[gridPaneWidth][gridPaneHeight] ;
for (Node child : gridPane.getChildren()) {
    Integer column = GridPane.getColumnIndex(child);
    Integer row = GridPane.getRowIndex(child);
    if (column != null && row != null) {
        gridPaneNodes[column][row] = child ;
    }
}
```

(or, you could just keep track of which were placed in which cell when you put them there...)

Then you can do

```
for (int row = 0; row < gridPaneHeight; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; row < gridPaneWidth; col++) {
        Node node = gridPaneNodes[column][row] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it array type of Node?