# Accessing fields in a JavaFX SceneBuilder app

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Intellij IDEA + Oracle JDK 14 + JavaFX 14

I'm making a simple JavaFX calculator-style app, and using SceneBuilder.

Is there an easier way to reference the fields in a SceneBuilder-built app, other than referring to individual unique `fx:id`'s? For example, if I have a UI built in SceneBuilder that has some rows and columns of data:

```
---------------------
| field00 | field01 |
| field10 | field11 |
---------------------
```

and I want to do some math on the data. Is there an easier way to reference the fields other than referring to static names?

```
@FXML private TextField field00;
@FXML private TextField field01;
@FXML private TextField field10;
@FXML private TextField field11;
```

I'm doing what has to be super naive stuff like: `if field00 is not null and if field01 is not null and ...`. I've made it a bit better by creating a class to represent each row and I'm reading those objects into an ArrayList, but my code to create the objects is still ugly stuff like:

```
RowList myRowList = new RowList();

MyRowClass aRow =
    new MyRowClass(
        Double.parseDouble(field00.getText()),
        Double.parseDouble(field01.getText()));
myRowList.addRow(aRow);

aRow =
    new Assignment(
        Double.parseDouble(field10.getText()),
        Double.parseDouble(field11.getText()));
myRowList.addRow(aRow);
```

I'd like to be able to iterate through the fields in some way.

Also, I'd like to add an "add a row" button to the UI and include that row in the calculations which would introduce some non-statically named fields to the mix.

Is the solution here to skip SceneBuilder and create the UI directly in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the TextFields inside a container such as a HBox, you can use the `.getChildren()` method on the container object to get all of its children nodes. You could then loop through all of them like this:

```
HBox h = new HBox();
h.getChildren().add(new TextField());
h.getChildren().add(new TextField());
h.getChildren().add(new TextField());

// loop through each node in the HBox
for (Node n : h.getChildren())
{
    // if the Node is of type TextField, and the text inside is not null
    if (n instanceof TextField && ((TextField) n).getText() != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: `getChildren()` on the `GridPane` in my app is what I needed, thank you, but I think this has revealed a weakness in my model. I want to process the table one row at a time. I don't think `GridPane` has anything that allows row-by-row processing (other than checking row and column indexes manually). I might be better off using a "stack" of hboxes instead, so I can iterate over all the hboxes / rows, and then iterate within each hbox / row.

Comment: In that case, you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145884/javafx-iterate-gridpane-nodes-per-row-read-nodes-of-gridpane-per-row) helpful